# Live website is not showing the changes I've made

Tags: cache, server, hosting

I used to have my website hosted through Godaddy and 4 months ago something weird started happening. Every time that I would make changes to my site, it wouldn't show up on the live website. The only exception was the homepage. Every change on the homepage would show up on the live website.

I did what everyone then told me to do, which was to flush the caches, tell Godaddy to flush their server's caches etc... The usual protocol. But nothing happened. So I then copied the content from the pages that weren't updating and I created new pages with the same content as the old pages. And these pages showed up on the live website perfectly. So I figured that I had found a solution to this problem.

Now, a couple of months later, I wanted to switch to a new server because as everyone knows, Godaddy's shared hosting system can really slow down your website. So I had my website switched to DigitalOcean a few days ago. But now, the same problem has started all over again.

The thing is, now the Homepage along with the entire site doesn't even show the new changes anymore, and the live website is showing the exact same website that it was showing 4 months ago. On the backend of my Wordpress site, everything is the way that it's supposed to be. The pages are the way that they are supposed to look, but every time that I click Update Page, it never updates to my new website.

This problem can't be on the server side, as my site has been switched to a new server and this problem still persists. I really need help with this and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me out.

Thank you all so very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable caching plugins
2. Purge cache from browser
3. Have you altered [caching](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) yourself in any way?
4. If youre using any CDN like Cloudflare, enable dev mode and purge cache from their side
5. Refresh page with `shift` + `F5` which ignores cache
6. If you're making changes in CSS or JS for example, make sure to take a look at source code in dev panel - maybe your CSS selectors are just not superior or you've got an error in other code.

If none of that helps, it's your host.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My exp with GoDaddy host site is that sometimes there's a lag before things are updated.  I once updated the style.css file and it took a while before the file is updated.  I have no idea why.

As for your issue, can you do the following:

- update WP, disable all plug-ins, and use the default WP themes (Twenty-Five) and see if that helps.   Based on what you say, this is probably where the problem is.
- upload an image and see if you can access the file online.  If you cannot, then you need to contact your hosting provider
- after you update the page, are you sure you are checking the actual page and not just the preview version?  The preview version just stuck to a specific change.  Any later changes will not show up.